# Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: web3js, blockchain, evm, gas-estimate

I am trying to call the following solidity method from my smart contract in javascript:

```
address[] public investors;

 function addInvestor(address investor) public {
        investors.push(investor);
    }


========================Javascript code===================

const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://goerli.infura.io/v3/c21338274bfc4a2ca6d4cb88789ed820');
const tokenContractABI = require('./abi.json');
const tokenContractAddress = '0x5fB7bFD1ac3804934E9Dbc32398C330B69826894'; 
const investor = '0xFBBd1c24C8e68831bD8c3e82b305df8fb70494a6';
const privateKey = '9XXX';

const tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenContractABI, tokenContractAddress);


async function callAddInvestor() {
    try {
        const sender = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
        const gasLimit = 22000; 
        const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender.address);

        const functionCall = tokenContract.methods.addInvestor(investor); 
        const encodedABI = functionCall.encodeABI();

        const transactionObject = {
            to: '0x5fB7bFD1ac3804934E9Dbc32398C330B69826894',
            gas: gasLimit,
            gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
            data: encodedABI,
            nonce: nonce,
            chainId: 5
        };

        const signedTransaction = await sender.signTransaction(transactionObject);
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
        const investors = await tokenContract.methods.investors().call();
        console.log('Get investors :', investors);
        console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

callAddInvestor();
```

I am getting the error:

Error: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
"blockHash": "0xe8ec781840bf6a4c108763d9896bb9bd15a72e4b53c7c87e42d2791fdb6b5325",
"blockNumber": 9012380,
"contractAddress": null,
"cumulativeGasUsed": 13157800,
"effectiveGasPrice": 3350701364,
"from": "0x18469cf4878b00ea90bf9b9fe8b06e026d400ba7",
"gasUsed": 22000,
"logs": [],
"logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"status": false,
"to": "0x5fb7bfd1ac3804934e9dbc32398c330b69826894",
"transactionHash": "0x7c2a199bfc759c08a927c4b4caf23e5dc0acf77e4f1e9997c15999488b26a685",
"transactionIndex": 58,
"type": "0x0"
}